# How to efficient parallel matrix multiplication for small external indices and large internal indices in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a matrix multiplication, `A[na,nb]*B[nb,nc]=C[na,nc]`. `na` and `nc` are small, `nb` is large. How to efficient parallel in this case? (if `na` and `nc` are large, that would be straightforward, to split external dimension)

I tried the following code

```
Program test_dgemm

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64, li => int64
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: a
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: b
    Real( dp ), Dimension( :, : ), Allocatable :: c
  
    Integer :: na, nb, nc, m_iter
    Integer :: i, j, k
    Integer( li ) :: start, finish, rate
    Integer :: numthreads

    real(dp) :: sum_time1, sum_time2

    Write( *, * ) 'numthreads'
    Read( *, * ) numthreads

    call omp_set_num_threads(numthreads)  

    Write( *, * ) 'na, nb, nc?'
    Read( *, * ) na, nb, nc
    Allocate( a ( 1:na, 1:nb ) ) 
    Allocate( b ( 1:nb, 1:nc ) )  
    Allocate( c( 1:na, 1:nc ) )
  
  
  !A[a,b] * B[b,c] = C[a,c]
    Call Random_number( a )
    Call Random_number( b )
    c  = 0.0_dp
 
    m_iter = 100
  



    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    do m = 1, m_iter    
        c  = 0.0_dp 
        Call System_clock( start, rate )

        do i = 1, na
            do j = 1, nc
                do k = 1, nb
                c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
                end do  
            end do 
        end do    

        Call System_clock( finish, rate )
        sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    end do  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop-1', sum_time1 / m_iter



    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    do m = 1, m_iter     
        c  = 0.0_dp 

        Call System_clock( start, rate )

        do i = 1, na
            do j = 1, nc
                !$omp parallel
                !$omp do private(k) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:c)
                do k = 1, nb
                    c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
                end do  
                !$omp end do
                !$omp end parallel
            end do 
        end do    


        Call System_clock( finish, rate )
        sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    end do  



    Write( *, * ) 'Time for loop-1-omp', sum_time1 / m_iter

    sum_time1 = 0.0  
    do m = 1, m_iter    
        Call System_clock( start, rate )

        c = matmul(a, b)

        Call System_clock( finish, rate )
        sum_time1 = sum_time1 + Real( finish - start, dp ) / rate  
    end do  
    Write( *, * ) 'Time for matmul', sum_time1 / m_iter
    write (*,*) c(1,1)


end
```

in `gfortran`, `numthreads=2`,
na, nb, nc?
1 1000000 1

I got

```
 Time for loop-1   1.4981370000000003E-003
 Time for loop-1-omp   2.1211667000000007E-002
 Time for matmul   3.1485730000000000E-003
```

that omp/matmul does not help. I may try to define a few intermediate matrices, e.g., A1[na,1:nb/2] B1[1:nb/2,nc], A2[na,nb/2+1:nb] B2[nb/2+1:nb,nc] and each thread handles one, then sum over all product matrices. Is there any simpler method by modifying the above omp section?

P.S. `Collapse` is not the option here. A related project has some nested loop to utilize symmetry of tensor, e.g., loop over upper triangle. `Collapse` requires perfect loop, which is not applicable.

Comment: `schedule(dynamic)` is not needed and has more overheads than the default static schedule.

Comment: But the real problem is that the arithmetic intensity of such a limit case (na=nb=1) is low, meaning that the code is memory-bound rather than compute-bound. If you multiply 2 NxN matrices the volume that is read/written from/to the memory is 3*N^2 words and there are N^3 fma (fused-multiply-add) operations to perform: the ratio is N/3. In contrast, when you multiply a 1xN matrix by a Nx1 matrix, the data volume is 2*N+1 and there are N fma operations: the ratio ~1/2. With such a low ratio you cannot expect an efficient parallelization, as most of time is spent reading/writing from/to the RAM.

Comment: Try with slightly larger values for na and nb (say 5): very likely the parallel version will be faster than the sequential one.

Comment: I think you should compare your timings with a simple use of matmul(); I imagine that has already been heavily optimised. I also seem to recall (from using a certain other language where matmul() wasn't available) that it was beneficial to transpose one matrix first, so as to use the natural contiguous order and consequent storage in cache memory.

Comment: Thanks. I will compare with `matmul` and check how to parallel it. Comment out `schedule(dynamic)` helps, even `na=nc=1`. When do I need or not need `schedule(dynamic)`? Never understand it properly. @PierU

Comment: `schedule(dynamic)` can be useful when the workload is unbalanced between the different iterations, which is not the case here.

Comment: When `na` and `nc` are 1, this is fine to put the parallel loop in the 2 encompassing loops but these 2 loops are actually useless. When `na` and `nc` are bigger, the overhead of the parallel work sharing can become significant compared to the parallel work and thus results in an inefficient execution. Moving the parallel loop so there is one section should help a bit but the main issue is the number of parallel for.

Comment: Besides, note that many BLAS (like OpenBLAS) have threshold value to detect cases where multiple threads can help. The threshold for OpenBLAS is not great (it is high and the detection is not very clever resulting in an inefficient execution for wide/long matrices like here). The MKL should do a better job here but I do not expect it to be optimal (or even close to).